# How to use only intel graphics and power off radeon with proprietary Catalyst drivers?

Tags: ati, intel-graphics, radeon, hybrid-graphics, catalyst

I've been using Linux for quite a while in everyday computing and programming. 
But now i got this new laptop with amazing battery life on windows which runs pretty cool even while gaming. But for some reason on Ubuntu I get like 1/3 battery life and it gets hot even while browsing the web.

I have the proprietary drivers for radeon, but I'm thinking about upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04, and I would like to know how can I use only the Intel graphics and have radeon always turned off? Since I do not need the discrete graphics on Ubuntu and I'm pretty sure my problem is related to the radeon sucking up my battery and generating heat.

My laptop technical specifications are:

- Dell latitude 3540
- Intel core i7 4500U (with Intel hd4400 graphics
  )
- Ati Radeon HD 8850m with 2GB GDDR5 VRAM
- 8 GB DDR3L @1600mhz
- Toshiba 256gb SSD
- Ubuntu 12.4.3

If you need any additional info, please tell me :)

Comment: Check you BIOS. Sometimes it lets you turn one or the other off.

Comment: @luizrogeriocn This could be a very useful read for you: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Catalyst Control Center:

[image]

Open your Terminal and execute:

> sudo apt-get install fglrx

Then reboot.

Comment: Great! I had tried this in the past using another laptop on ubuntu 13.04 and if i chose the Intel option it would end up with a black screen upon reboot. But now on ubuntu 14.04 and with this new laptop it worked like a charm. Battery life went from ~3hrs to ~7hrs, and my temps are at least 15 to 20 degrees celsius cooler. Now I can finally use ubuntu for everyday computing and let windows only for gaming. Thanks a lot, dude :D

Comment: Glad help you +luirogejdebje! :)